# Render a Image that is within a folder passing it as a prop with styled-components library in React

Tags: reactjs, rendering, styled-components, react-props

I need some help Guys, I am new in React and I haven't find an unswer to this problem.
it's not working and even don't show the error in the console, follow the code:

the ONLY Message in the console:

> The component styled.div with the id of "sc-dYPfWK" has been created
> dynamically.You may see this warning because you've called styled
> inside another component. To resolve this only create new
> StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.

Data that I am passing:

```
export const data = [
 {
  title: 'Model S',
  backgroundImg: 'model-s.jpg',
 },
 {
  title: 'Model Y',
  backgroundImg: 'model-y.jpg',
 },
]
```

Parental Component:

```
import Section from './Section';
import { data } from "../data";

const Home = () => {
 return (
   <Container>
    {data.map(item => (
     <Section 
        key={item.title} 
        title={item.title} 
        backgroundImg={item.backgroundImg} 
        description='Order Online for Touchless Delivery' 
        leftBtn='Custom Order' 
        rightBtn='Existing Inventory' />
    ))}
  
   </Container>
 )
}

export default Home
```

The Child Components and styled-components:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import downArrow from '../images/down-arrow.svg'

const Section = (props) => {
 return (
  <Wrap img={props.backgroundImg} >
    {...a lot of other things}
  </Wrap>
)}

export default Section

const Wrap = styled.div`
 background-image: url('../images/${props => props.img}');
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to write this part

```
const Wrap = styled.div`
   background-image: url('../images/${props => props.img}');
`
```

before the Section declaration?

Comment: No bro, it didn't have any effect the order of the component. I think it's because of the structural folders that are holding my imgs, so it's no terrible at all, because I will just work with api repositories fo images and this is a minor project. I will just create a img tag and style it in my Wrap boundaries.